# How do I set the ASP.NET Core "amr" claim to "mfa" if "RememberMachine" is true?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, multi-factor-authentication

I am enabling Multi-Factor Authentication for my ASP.NET Core (v7.x) MVC application.

It seems to be working perfectly until I check the "Remember Machine" checkbox. As expected, Identity is creating a "Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe" cookie, and is setting the "amr" claim to "mfa" when completing the MFA sequence. If I log out and back in, Identity correctly skips the MFA sequence, but the "amr" claim is set to "pwd". I therefore cannot enforce any "Must Use MFA" authorization requirements using the "amr" claim.

Is this by design?

I am largely following the template code, which I have brought from the Razor Pages implementation to one using MVC. I verified that the same "problem" occurs in an app that uses the raw template code in Razor Pages.

I've seen suggestions to add a new, custom claim that can identify whether a user is using a "remembered" MFA result. This is defeating the built-in mechanism of the "amr" claim, in my opinion. Before I go into overriding pieces of the SignInManager I wanted to see if (1) anyone else has "noticed" or experienced this same issue, and (2) anyone has "fixed" the problem using the "amr" claim without overriding anything.